# Web colors hexadecimal notation

Tags: css, user-interface, colors, hex

Usually colors in hexadecimal notation are presented with a hashtag following 6 hexadecimal characters. What color does the value #AAA produce? Are the other characters derived from the existing ones? Are the missing values just assumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question.

Short answer: #xyz is read as #xxyyzz, so the specific example means #aaa becomes #aaaaaa, a gray quite dark tone (68.75%).

Wikipedia calls this shorthand hex form, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Shorthand_hexadecimal_form

CSS does have a formal specification, but it is a very long read. To experiment with the specific colors that CSS allows, maybe browser debuggers is good. jsfiddle is also a possibility: http://jsfiddle.net/mYdb5/
which contains the following simple code:

```
Color test:<br/>
<div/>

div {
    background-color: #aaa;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}
```

Comment: `#aaaaaa` (or `#aaa`) is a lighter tone. `#777777` (`#777`) is a mid-grey and `#333333` (`#333`) a rather dark tone, with `#ffffff` (`#fff`) being white and `#000000` (`#000`) being black. Particularly in CSS, [colour names can also be used to address codes too](http://rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm), such as `black`, `darkgray`, `gray`, `silver` and `white`.

Comment: @Paul Dark/light... Well, the code block background here above is #eff0f1 (Jul 19 2016) and is quite bright. See this screenshow with the answer text block above painted #aaaaaa (= #aaa) and judge yourselves if it feels like a dark or light gray: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bj8dzh59hgfac54/Screenshot%202016-07-19%2011.13.45.png?dl=0

But if we ignore the impression and just care about numbers, then I agee that #aaaaaa is far more than halfway from #000000 to #ffffff and maybe you would argue that dark is between #000000 and #7fffff ?

Comment: Wow!  That took you a while to get back!  ;o)  The other factor, I suppose, to take into account is how the user has set up their monitor; this directly affects the range of shades and colours you can see.

Answer (score 3):

`#AAA` is interpreted as `#AAAAAA`

When you have 3-hexadecimal colour, the browser is assuming that every single char (or number) gets doubled (so e.g. `#ABC` is equivalent to `#AABBCC`)

Answer (score 3):

The six digit colours are traditional 24 bit colours, whereas the three character colour codes are "[web-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Web-safe_colors)" colours...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors

Comment: No. #000 to #fff gives 4095 possible colors. Web-safe was limited to 216 colors :(. Re-check your source.

Specifically; #aaa is not included among the 216 "web-safe" colors.